# Orchard CMS Sidebar Menu

Tags: navigation, orchardcms, styling

Obviously this might be a simple question, yet I can't manage to get it done.

I have a Main menu on top. Now I want to add a different menu pointing to the actions of my controller in my module in a sidebar. So I have created a menu widget and a layer depicting the pages of my module. I have placed the widget on this layer in the sidebar. But this generates the same layout for my menu (the horizontal oriented menu)

So I thought I would create an alternate view for this menu. But the only alternate that contains the name of my widget is a wrapper. And no matter what I do in the alternate wrapper it does not get reflected on the page. Because I would like to have the sidebar menu vertical instead of horizontal.

Next attemt was downloading a theme that had a side bar menu. In the gallery there is Dark 2.0.0 theme by BindTuning. This one had a nice sidebar. Happily I went into the widgets section expecting two menuwidgets. But instead I just found one placed in the Navigation Zone. Taking a closer look into their template files and I see that the sidebar menu is generated via a jscript converting the horizontal menu into vertical menu (still dont know the use of having the same menu twice on the page, but thats another discussion). So no help there.

It seems so obvious, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as alternate wrappers. You can get widget alternates by enabling the alternate widget feature.

Comment: I guess I should've dived into the CMS part first instead of deep diving immediately into Module development :)